# Error when trying to debug a 64-bit console application

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I try to debug a simple 64-bit console application in Delphi 10.3.3 Rio:

```
program ShellLinkShortcutTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  JclShell,
  System.SysUtils;

const
  ShortcutFile = 'R:\myshortcut.lnk';
  ShortcutTarget = 'C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe';

function SaveShortcutShellLink(const AFile: string): string;
var
  SL: JclShell.TShellLink;
  HR: Integer;
begin
  Result := 'error';

  SL.Target := ShortcutTarget;
  SL.Description := 'My description';
  HR := JclShell.ShellLinkCreate(SL, AFile);
end;

begin
  try
    Writeln(SaveShortcutShellLink(ShortcutFile));
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

[image]

But as soon as I press F9 I get this error message:

[image]

What is even more strange: The file **wmcipc.cpp** does not exist!

However, debugging the same program as 32-bit works without problems.

My OS: Windows 7 x64 SP1

What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to see where that error is occurring?

Comment: As I said, as soon as I press F9 the error message appears. So I cannot even step through the code.

Comment: Are you setting breakpoints on the first line of code?  Your code compiles but does not throw the error you are seeing on my box.  I was able to step into the code by setting a breakpoint on the writeln statement and follow the code down toward the error.  Your SaveSHortcutShellLink always returns 'error' and doesn't check the HR return.

Comment: This has nothing to do with code. It seems that debugging is broken on my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But as soon as I press F9 I get this error message:

That is a very old and well-known error in the Delphi 64-bit debugger:

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=712725 (link dead, here is an [archive.org snapshot from December 8th, 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20161208001235/https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=712725))

It has a simple fix:

> Open a command prompt as Administrator, and run
>
> `netsh winsock reset`
>
> After rebooting, your 64-bit debugger should work again.
>
> This will remove any other winsock LSPs that you have, so you will need to re-install them. (firewalls, security software, etc.)

---

> What is even more strange: The file **wmcipc.cpp** does not exist!

It is not supposed to exist on your machine.  You are seeing an assertion error raised from the debugger itself, not from your project.  The `wmcipc.cpp` source file is internal to the debugger's implementation.